# TFS vNext build Error SQL72027 File Does Not Exists For SQL Database Project

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, sql-server-data-tools

Thanks in advance for reading this.

Unable to create a vNext Build for a composite SQL Server database project (that has a database reference). The Build is to push code from our on-premise TFS to a Dev database.

We're using VS 2015 Update 3 to create the SQL Server database project and we've TFS 2015 update 2.

In the SQL Server database project let's say you added a database reference called `MyReference.dacpac` (and the referenced dacpac sits in another TFS folder in the same Team Project):

How source control in TFS looks like:

```
-- MyTeam
 ---- DEV
  ------ Database
  ------ Common (where referenced dacpac is located)
  ------ BuildTest.Database
```

The vNext build error is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(550,5): Error SQL72027: File "E:\Root\TFS2015\Dev\Database\Common\MyReference.dacpac" does not exist.

Here's part of the build definition:

[image]

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Where does E: come from - is that the drive that the build agent is using, or could that be a local path a developer has checked in?

Comment: @DaveShaw, E drive I believe is on the build server that the build agent is using. Thanks!

Comment: Does the project build successfully locally?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, yes, it builds successfully.

Comment: Can you check the "Mappings" setting under "Repository" tab of your build definition to see if the "Common" folder is included? And also check the logs to see if the file is downloaded during the Get Source Step.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT, sorry for the late reply. Yes, in 'Mappings' there is "Common". The log we see that it's pulling the referenced dacpac-- "Getting E:\Root\_work\4\s\MyTeam\Dev\Database\Common". BUT, the path of where it's looking for the dacpac: "E:\Root\TFS2015\Dev\Database\Common\MyReference.dacpac". The path used in the DB project for database reference is: "C:\TFS2015\Dev\Database\Common". BUT, when tried relative path f with "..\" it's referencing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\". Strange.

Comment: What's the detailed path you use with "..\"? I just created a sql project with relative path to dacpac file, the build can be finished successfully with vNext build.

Comment: Finally got it to build. 

Here are the issues: (embrassing) 
1. Found out that BuildTest.Database is not under the DEV folder. But sits in another folder (MyTeam/UserName) on the same level as DEV.
2. Found out that  BuildTest.Database did not match the workspace mapping. Instead of "C:\TFS2015\UserName" it's "C:\Users\UserName\...\BuildTest.Database". This explains why I thought the relative path wasn't working

To get it to build:
1. To get it to work BuildTest.Database had to be under the DEV folder.
2. Get it to follow the workspace mapping

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow down the issue, please try the items below:

1. Check whether the MyReference.dacpac under path E:\Root\TFS2015\Dev\Database\Common on your build agent machine
2. Log on to your build agent machine, and run the project manually with MSBuild command line, to check the result.
3. Check how do you reference MyReference.dacpac locally, and check the source directory on your build agent machine to see whether the structure of the project is the same as local.

Comment: is build agent machine and build server two different boxes? for #2, "run the project manually' means on that box we use TFS to pull down the project? Or do we copy it to a network folder? We will need to cooperate with the TFS admin and report back. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on where your build agent deployed. Run project manually means run the project with MSBuild command line instead of TFS Build. You can try both the project get from TFS and copy the project to build agent machine.

Comment: This was also really helpful to narrow down the issue. Thank you again!